# Adding concurrent editing support in drawing tool in a React + Spring Boot + Mysql application

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, collaborative-editing

I am working on a web application with a front-end built using React-Redux and a backend built using Spring Boot + Mysql + Redis. Basically, in order to do any operation, the front-end makes an API call.

Here we have developed an in-house drawing library using React-Redux and this drawing library is used in my app. Now, the requirement is to support concurrent editing of a diagram in our web app.

In this context, I have found several articles:

1. [How conflicts are resolved in Collaborative Editing software that utilizes Operational Transformations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69870537/how-conflicts-are-resolved-in-collaborative-editing-software-that-utilizes-opera)
2. https://medium.com/pictet-technologies-blog/build-a-collaborative-web-application-using-reactive-programming-b6d6b8c9aef4

But, I have not found any concrete idea regarding how to achieve this in my application.

Could anyone please give some pointers regarding this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [websocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) to synchronize data between the different users.

[This](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) tuto can help.